# How to prove $F$ is continuous, given that $F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y)$ and $F$ is continuous at a point $a$?

Tags: continuity, proof-writing

I have this problem for my maths class.

[image]

I would like a step in the right direction, but not a full solution as I want to prove it myself.

I have two definitions of continuity: The "the limit exists and is equal to the value" one and the "epsilon-delta" one.

Comment: also proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10040/203665). I'm fairly sure it's been asked before, but can't find the other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $z_n \to z$. We want to show that $F(z_n) \to F(z)$ to show continuity. Well, we know that $F$ is continuous at $a$. So, since $z_n - z +a \to a$, we have that $F(z_n - z + a) \to F(a)$. But $F(z_n - z+a) = F(z_n - z) + F(a)$, so we must have that $F(z_n - z) \to 0$. Applying the pseudo-linearity property once more,
we get that $F(z_n) - F(z) \to 0$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Which is the full answer. But it's hard to  give only a hint for such a short answer.  ...........+1

Comment: What does $z_n$, $z_n \to z$ and $F(z_n) \to F(z)$ mean? I do not know what your arrow sign means, as "implies" does not work in this context.

Comment: $z_n$ would be a sequence of reals, $\to$ means tends to, so $z_n \to z$ means that the sequence $z_n$ tends to $z$ oe $z$ is the limit of $z_n$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: What is the pseudo-linearity property? Also, isn't all you can conclude that $F(z_n)+F(-z) \to 0$?

Comment: The pseudo-linearity property is that $F(x+y) = F(x)+F(y)$. From this you can get that $F$ is linear over $\mathbb{Q}$, but not $\mathbb{R}$. To say $a_n\to a$ means the sequence of numbers $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$. Hope this helps.

Comment: How can you tell that $F(-x) = -F(x)$?

Comment: $0 = F(0) = F(x-x) = F(x) +F(-x)$.

To see that $F(0) =0$, note that $F(0) = F(0+0) = F(0)+ F(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n)$ a sequence with $\lim_nx_n=x$ we have $\lim_n x_n-x+a=a$; $\lim_nF(x_n)=\lim F(x_n-x+a+x-a)=\lim_nF(x_n-x+a)+F(x-a)=$ since  $F$ is continuous an $a$, $\lim_nF(x_n-x+a)=F(a)$. We deduce that:

$F(a)+F(x)-F(a)=F(x)$`.

Comment: My edit was to precede lim with \ so it looks better....+1